# Rendering a layout within a layout in yii2 advanced template

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app

Am new to yii2. Am trying to nest a layout within a layout but its not working

Layout main (Contains the nav bar)

```
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
 NavBar::begin([
            'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
            'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
            ],
        ]);
$menuItems = [
            ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
           .............................
        ];

        echo Nav::widget([
            'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
            'items' => $menuItems,
        ]);
        NavBar::end();
    ?>
<div class="container">
    <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
        'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
    ]) ?>
    <?= Alert::widget() ?>
    <?= $content ?>
    </div>
</div>
 <?php $this->endBody() ?>
```

The other layout applicationLayout

```
<?php $this->beginPage('//layouts/main') ?>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                           <div class="container">
                                <?= $content ?>
                            </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

In the controller i have rendered applicationLayout but it doesnt display the main layout That is that it doesn't display the nav bar

Comment: use `yii\base\View::render()` in view file. this is equivalent to `renderPartial()` of controller.


                     Reference: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1925#issuecomment-32160549

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `<?= $this->render('//layouts/main') ?>` or `<?php echo $this->render('//layouts/main') ?>` Check the path is correct too.

Comment: Comment the `<?= $content ?>` line in Layout main

Comment: After commenting the line and having added the line as follows<?php $this->beginPage('<?= $this->render('//layouts/main') ?'') ?>  in the application layout the two layouts get distorted such that it turns to plain html without the styling. Both layouts are using different assets